# Target id with selected option

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

The option is not being targeted.
And I need to add to jquery to show the option or populate the other div with the dropdown option the user chooses.
Ok, I know I am doing something simple. Basically when a user clicks on an option on the drop down the event div will appear. Also the option clicked will appear in another div. Please let me know what I am missing or if you need more info. I know I am on the right track.

So here is the jquery I have thus far:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#event").hide();
    $("#myselect option:selected").click(function() {
      $("#event").show();
     });
});
```

How I have the html and form is like so:

Where the div is hidden and then showed and where option value will be displayed

```
<div id="event" class="phone_button">Add Event</div>
```

Where the drop_down form is populated with an array.

```
<?php
            $options = array(
                '1' => '1',
                '2' => '2',
            );
        ?>

        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
                    <div class="row">

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">

                        <p>If you have previously created a template for your digital banner please select it from the list, otherwise select no template.</p>
                        <form>
                        <select id="whatever" name="name_of_selectbox">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">Test</option>
                        <option value="2">Testing</option>
                        </select>
                        </form>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p>You can add an event created in MyApplication.</p>

            </div>
```

Comment: you can't use events on `option` tag. Not 100% clear what the expected behavior is. Please post html not server code for your `<select>` and explain behavior in better detail. WHat does `option appear in div` mean for example

Comment: @charlietfl Please see updated code without server code. Option appear in div means: The option value that says t

Comment: use `change()` on select, within change handler `this.value` is new value, still not sure what you are wanting since you originally had a change handler already that submits the form

Comment: @charlietfl Please see updated code without server code. Option appear in div means: The option value that says Test will appear or populate the option the user clicks on in another button right below the phone_button in event div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you are looking for is to display `#event` if an option other than `select` is selected then

```js
$(function() {
  $("#events").hide();
  $("#myselect select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
    if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
      $('<li />', {
        'data-value': $selected.val(),
        text: $selected.text()
      }).appendTo('#events');
      $selected.addClass('added')
    }
    $("#events").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#events li{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#events li:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="row">
        <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">

          <p>If you have previously created a template for your digital banner please select it from the list, otherwise select no template.</p>
          <form>
            <select id="whatever" name="name_of_selectbox">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="1">Test</option>
              <option value="2">Testing</option>
            </select>
          </form>
          <hr/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

</div>
<ul id="events"></ul>
```

Comment: I need your help man on this post if your available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188556/hide-or-show-div-if-status-is-active-or-inactive-by-data-key

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
   $("#event").hide();
   $("#myselect").change(function() {
     $("#event").show();
     $("#another_div").html($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
   });
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?