# Hide or show div if status is active or inactive by data key

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I need to toggle a hide or show button based on a status id. If status is active=1 then show delete button only. If status is inactive=0 then show only reactivated button. But if status active or inactive is shown it has to bring in the corresponding data as well from the table.

Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187896/codeigniter-two-conditions-with-same-variable-breaking-statement 
for background on this new question. In the previous question I wanted to solve my problem using php. Now I have resorted to Jquery to make it simpler. However, I am having trouble setting up the function to toggle the hide and show button.

I have already setup my data in the markup which I think is correct.

How should I setup this function to achieve the results I need.

```
<div class="container-d" style="padding-left:0;"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 section-header buffer-bottom-md">
        <h1>Users</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
      <?php 
     /*start a1 : show delete message on success*/
     if($this->session->flashdata('ses_user_deleted'))
     {
   ?>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('ses_user_deleted');?>
     </div>
   </div>
   <?php
     }
     /*end a1 : show delete message on success*/
   ?>
   <?php /*start : email search form - line no 23 to 43*/?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 buffer-bottom-md"> <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php 
      $attributes = array('style' => 'padding:0;');
      echo form_open(base_url('users/index'), $attributes);
      ?>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td><?php
             $data_email = array('name'  => 'email_id', 'class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' =>'Email');
             echo form_input($data_email);
            ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/ >
          <?php echo anchor("users/reset","reset");?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<?php /*end : email search form*/ ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
    <table class ="table">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>User Id</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Company</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Telephone</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Mobile</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Website</strong></td>
            <td><strong>status</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <?php
                if (isset($show_all))
                    {
                        ?><td colspan=2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="<?php echo base_url('users/')?>">Show only active users</td><?php
                    }
                else
                    {
                        ?><td colspan=2><a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="<?php echo base_url('users/all')?>">Include deleted users</td><?php
                    }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    /*start a2 - show edit link for each user - changes made on line no36 and 48 */

      foreach($users as $row =>$value)
        {

               $status= (html_escape($value['status'])==0) ? "inactive" : "active";

              echo "<tr>
                      <td><a title = 'Click to view details of this user' href = '".base_url('Users/search/'.html_escape($value['id']))."'>".html_escape($value['id'])."</a></td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['username'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['firstName'])." ".html_escape($value['surName'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['company'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['telephone'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['mobile'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['email'])."</td>
                      <td>".html_escape($value['website'])."</td>
                      <td>".$status."</td>
                      <td><a href = " . base_url("users/edit/".html_escape($value['id'])) . ">Edit</a></td>";
                      //echo $status; die(); 


              echo "<td><div id='a' data-inactive='deleted'><a href = " . base_url('Users/delete/' . html_escape($value['id']));?> onclick = 'return confirm("Really delete this user?")'<?php echo ">Delete</a</td></div>";

              echo "<td><div id='i' data-active='active'><a href = " . base_url('Users/reactivate/' . html_escape($value['id']));?> onclick = 'return confirm("Reactivate this user?")'<?php echo ">Reactivate</a</td></div>";

              echo "</tr>";  
        }



        /*end a2- show edit link for each user*/
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php /*start a3 - call required jquery and bootstrap.js file to show delete message*/?>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <?php
  /*end a3 - call required jquery and bootstrap.js file to show delete message*/
  ?>
  <script>
 //var mydata = $( "a" ).data();

 $("#i").hide();

</script>
```

Comment: It seems adding the data in a div that wraps the td is breaking the column so I need to add data through <td> and have it targeted in corresponding js instead of targeting div id.

Comment: it will be better if you can share the generated html also

Comment: @ArunPJohny I will set it up now and check back in a few minutes.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ygbeuyky/2/

Comment: what is your requirement... I don't think it is clear...

Comment: @Arun P Johny Sorry I did not give you the background. It is all in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187896/codeigniter-two-conditions-with-same-variable-breaking-statement

Comment: The data is loaded via page refresh isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62445/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-bobby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problems is that your markup is broken! You can't have a div as a direct descendent of a `<tr>`, so move it inside your `td` and close your `<div`!!!

```
echo "<td><div id='active' data-inactive='deleted'><a href = " . base_url('Users/delete/' . html_escape($value['id']));?> onclick = 'return confirm("Really delete this user?")'<?php echo ">Delete</a</td></div>";

echo "<td><div id='inactive' data-active='active'><a href = " . base_url('Users/reactivate/' . html_escape($value['id']));?> onclick = 'return confirm("Reactivate this user?")'<?php echo ">Reactivate</a</td></div>";
```

Also, for a more elegant way to set your variable, try this instead of your if/else statement:

```
$status= (html_escape($value['status'])==0) ? "inactive" : "active";
```

Another issue you are having is that you have multiple instances of an id. change that active/inactive to a class or another data property.

Comment: I updated my changes to reflect what you said. Now I am at the point of simply selecting an id to hide to build my function. However when I hide this it only hides one link "reactivate" instead of every link in the foreach loop.

Comment: if you need this on more than one element, you need to use classes and not id's. id's have to be unique on a page... there can be only one '#active' or '#inactive' element per page. use classes instead of ids if you need to add more than one.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You can't wrap a TD in a DIV that breaks semantic markup.  You must put the DIV inside the TD.

Secondly you must not use the same ID (identifier) on multiple elements, this also breaks semantic mark up.  You should probably read up a bit more on proper HTML markup as well as the use of Javascript to target DOM elements.

Comment: I updated my changes to reflect what you said. Now I am at the point of simply selecting an id to hide to build my function. However when I hide this it only hides one link "reactivate" instead of every link in the foreach loop.